# how to solve adding with REGEX

Tags: regex, math

i want to get math equation only with addition such as 1+2+3 and return its result. i have the following code, and the problem is that it doesn't deal with doubles (i cant write 2.2+3.4)
 I tried to change the regex expression to `([\+-]?\d+.\d+)([\+-])(-?(\d+.\d+))` and now it doesnt deal with integers (i cant write 2+4). what should be the correct regex expression to deal with doubles and integers? thanx
the code:

```
        regEx = new Regex(@"([\+-]?\d+)([\+-])(-?(\d+))");
        m = regEx.Match(Expression, 0);
        while (m.Success)
        {
            double result;
            switch (m.Groups[2].Value)
            {
                case "+":

                    result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[1].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[3].Value);

                    if ((result < 0) || (m.Index == 0)) Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, DoubleToString(result), 1);
                    else Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, "+" + result, 1);
                    m = regEx.Match(Expression);
                    continue;
                case "-":
                    result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[1].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[3].Value);
                    if ((result < 0) || (m.Index == 0)) Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, DoubleToString(result), 1);
                    else Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, "+" + result, 1);
                    m = regEx.Match(Expression);
                    continue;
            }
        }
        if (Expression.StartsWith("--")) Expression = Expression.Substring(2);
        return Expression;
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to use something like String.Split()? Do you have to stick with regex?

Comment: applying `regex` solution for every problem is a very BAD idea....as Egor suggested,y not use `Split` function!

Comment: If you want to trying writing something that can parse and evaluate many mathematical expressions, by all means write a parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have stated, RegEx is *not* a good solution to this problem. You would be much better off with either a simple split statement (if you only want to support the `+` and `-` operators), or an actual parser (if you want to support actual mathematical expressions).

But, for the sake of explaining some RegEx, your problem is that `\d+.\d+` matches "one or more digits, followed by any character, followed by one or more digits." If you gave it an integer greater than 99, it would work, since you're matching `.` (any character) and not `\.` (specifically the dot character).

A simpler version would be `[\d\.]+`, which matches one-or-more digits-or-dots. The problems is that it allows multiple dots, so `8.8.8.8` is a valid match. So what you really want is `\d+\.?\d*`, which matches one-or-more digits, one-or-zero dots, and zero-or-more digits. Thus `2`, `2.`, and `2.05` are all valid matches.